# strange behavior with list and ndindex

Tags: python, list, numpy

I hope this is not redundant with another question but I would like to understand the following result I get when execute on a jupyter notebook :

```
f=np.zeros((2,5,7))
l = np.ndindex(f.shape)
count=0
for i in l:
    count+=1
print(count)
la = l
list(la)
count=0
for i in l:
    count+=1
print(count)

70
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per the documentation on ndindex

> An N-dimensional iterator object to index arrays.

It returns an iterator object. So `l` has an interator object. You then iterate through all items in the iterator and essentially the iterator is empty.

You then make `la` a copy of `l` so `la` now has the same iterator object thats in `l`. but `l` has already iterated it so there are no items left in it.

So when you then try to iterate over `la`, you dont go in the loop cause there are no items left in the iterator. you can see the same behaviour if you just try to iterate over `l` twice

Answer (score 2):

`nd.ndindex()` returns an iterator, which can only be iterated over once.

Answer (score 1):

You get an iterator object looking something like `<numpy.ndindex at 0x7facbb730950>`.

As described in dics - `.ndindex() returns : An N-dimensional iterator object to index arrays.`

Initially the pointer is set at `0th` index and to access the next element `__next__()` is called on the iterator.

Now you are iterating on the object in first loop which calls the `__next__()`, thus setting the current index pointer to last index of the iterator.

Now you are making a copy of iterator object with all the properties it has including the current index pointer.

So the second time you try to iterate you don't have any items left and thus the value of count remains `0`.